# Error: more than one library with package name com.google.android.gms.license

Tags: android, google-play-services, ionic3

When I try to run the command `ionic cordova build android` out error as title above. Then I try to remove one of the `gms`, when I build again the deleted it appears again. how to solve this?.

Here is my dependencies of my `build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+" // i remove this
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+"
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've faced this issue quite recently and the problem for me was that for some reason the android project.properties file was generated with different versions for the com.google.android.gms, as such:

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+
```

This makes the library.2 and library.3 require one version while the library.4 requires a more specific version, thus causing the duplicate library reference during compiling.

While I don't think this should be the final solution, adding the specific library worked for me. As such:

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+
```

Comment: Worked for me too - but like you say, editing project.properties can't be a final solution!

Comment: after changing like this when try to build Could not find any version that matches com.google.gms:google-services:11+.
     Versions that do not match:

Comment: I guess you'll have to change the values to match whichever version you are using. The key idea is that you have the same version for all the references

Answer (score 13):

in build.gradle add this

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
       force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0"
       force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"
       force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0"
       force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0"
       force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0"
       force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0"
       force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.8.0"
       force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
       force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
       force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
       force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0'
       force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
       force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
   }
}
```

if that doesn't work, search in your project the string '12.0.0' and add in the list above the missing library

Comment: This worked - thanks! I personally think placing this in build-extras.gradle would be better.

Answer (score 6):

This happening because of Play services 12.0.0. I went ahead and downgraded the dependencies to 11.8.0 ( last known working version for my project). I'm using react native. I had 2 dependencies which were pulling in 12.0.0 of google play services - com.google.android:play-services...12.0.0
Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your advice, the answer also helps my problem.. thank you

Answer (score 6):

Things i had to do to get the build to succeed on my Ionic3 App:

- Add Plugin cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release
- Remove and re-add the android platform
- 11.+ in platform/android/project.properties file for libraries ( Especially if you're using firebase )
- 11.+ for dependencies in platforms/android/cordova-plugin-firebase/-build.gradle
- The above changes in platforms/android/build.gradle

This might be the worst possible way to get things work, but kinda saved my life. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it related to new release of Google Play services 12.0.0(released at March 20, 2018)
I've resolved it fixing dependencies:
Add config in `android/build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    ...
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Add force (11.0.0 is version you want to use)
             force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0'
            force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.0'
            force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.0.0'
            force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:11.0.0'
        }
    }
}
}
```

Set of dependencies are from your `android/app/build.gradle`

Answer (score 4):

For reference, from: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

**Google APIs for Android**

**March 20, 2018 - Version 12.0.0**

**Known Issues with version 12.0.0**

- ...
- -license POM dependencies cause "more than one library with package name ‘com.google.android.gms.license'" issues in Ionic Pro.
- ...

We will provide an updated 12.0.1 release to address these issues soon.

---

***My Workaround***

(based on [jeremy castelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2246035/jeremy-castelli)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49408093/644634) and [keldar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038786/keldar)'s subsequent comment)

I am using the following workaround (and I stress, this is a workaround).

Add the following to the bottom of build-extras.gradle, creating the file if necessary.

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8+',
      'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8+',
      'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8+',
      'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8+',
      'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8+',
      'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.8+',
      'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8+'
  }
}
```

It is important to include all firebase and all android.gms library references, if you miss just one from here, it will still fail to build.  Grep your gradle files for all the references.  In my case I had missed firebase-auth which was referenced in the firebase plugin folder's .gradle file.

What [resolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) `force` does is override the version choices made by the project/plugins and force gradle to reference a specific version.

There is no need to edit project.properties or any other gradle files using this workaround.

Comment: So I see that this issue was fixed on March 28th. I downloaded the latest version of the Cordova Google Maps plugin yesterday but I still experienced this issue. Do we have to wait on a release of the Cordova Google Maps plugin as well?

Answer (score 3):

In my case

```
npm update
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@6.4.0
```

And replace in platform/android/projet.properties

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4+
```

To

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:26+
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

The cause of this error has been identified as a bug in [v12.0.0 of the Google Play Services library](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#march_20_2018_-_version_1200):

> **Known Issues with version 12.0.0**
>   -license POM dependencies cause "more than one library with package name ‘com.google.android.gms.license'" issues in Ionic Pro.

The bug has been fixed in [v12.0.1 of the Google Play Services library](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#march_28_2018_-_version_1201):

> Restores unique package names for runtime linked -license artifacts which affected some build systems' (e.g. Ionic Pro) compatibility issues.

Therefore specifying v12.0.1 or above of the Play Services Library via the [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) plugin resolves the issue, for example:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release  --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=12.+
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run the command **ionic cordova** you can change the version,I have the same error, and i fixed the problem by changing version my nodes modules, my plugin cordova, version off android studio.

**My conf below:**

ANDROID STUDIO: 3.0.0

```
pply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

```
// Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
// installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
// http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
// and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1' // google-services plugin
}
```

}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}

...
...
...
...
...

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Gradle version : 3.3
com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2

Some times node module and cordova plugin gets himself wrong, so you do delete manually in the folder.
Don’t forget to remove and add cordova plugin when you update it.

Try to go in android studio => files => project structure => project =>ok
Normally android studio should synchonize your gradle

**OR**

**Error: more than one library with package name com.google.android.gms.license**

In my case, the problem was because I was including:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
```

both the wearable play services, and the regular. I commented out the wearable part, and it works. 
Not sure if I'll need it, but it was included by default by the project wizard

I hope I can help you. Keep going !

Answer (score 2):

just change platform/android/project.properties  to

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+
```

this  worked for me

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.

```
node_modules/react-native-camera/android/build.gradle:
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0' // update by me on 
    20180321
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was a matter of adding version number to Google Play Services in **project.properies** file.

So you need to change something like:

```
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:
```

to:

```
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.
```

Answer (score 1):

Only this worked for me in `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
                    details.useVersion '11.8.0'
                }
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                    details.useVersion '11.8.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/857#issuecomment-375243825

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Go to project.properties (in your platform folder)

**2.** I was using just google analytics in my "project.properties" and had to add " 11.+" to the end of the version and that worked for me. Not sure if that's long term fix but it did the trick.

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.+
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error in my ionic project, after little search I have read about to upgrade the Android platform which is required for latest Android Gradle Plugin in order to build the app.

**The solution to is very easy** just follow the below mentioned step.

1. Remove your existing Anroid platform

> ionic cordova platform remove android

2. Add minimum version Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 through Android SDK Manager to use latest Android Gradle Plugin in order to build the app
3. Add minimum version for Android platform

> ionic cordova platform add android@^6.4.0