# react-native - more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

Tags: react-native

i know it causes due to google new version update of gms to 12.0.0 here is link https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

add in `android/build.gradle` but now its not compiling onesignal coz it also uses Google service with different version

other solution on github suggest me to add '+' in dependencies but it's not working

```
configurations.all {
            // #PlayServicesGate — March, 20 2018
            resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'

            // Firebase dependencies
            force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"
            force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
            force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
            }
        }
```

please let me know if anyone know about this

```
    :react-native-onesignal:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerV4Impl1200Library
    :react-native-onesignal:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerV4ImplLicense1200Library
    :react-native-onesignal:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1200Library
    :react-native-onesignal:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasksLicense1200Library
    :react-native-onesignal:prepareComOnesignalOneSignal382Library
    :react-native-onesignal:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library
    :react-native-onesignal:prepareReleaseDependencies
    :react-native-onesignal:compileReleaseAidl
    :react-native-onesignal:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :react-native-onesignal:compileLint
    :react-native-onesignal:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
    :react-native-onesignal:compileReleaseRenderscript
    :react-native-onesignal:generateReleaseBuildConfig
    :react-native-onesignal:generateReleaseResValues
    :react-native-onesignal:generateReleaseResources
    :react-native-onesignal:mergeReleaseResources
    :react-native-onesignal:processReleaseManifest
    :react-native-onesignal:processReleaseResources FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':react-native-onesignal:processReleaseResources'.
    > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 3 mins 7.465 secs
    Error: /Users/vsts/agent/2.131.0/work/1/s/android/gradlew failed with return code: 1
        at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/vsts/agent/2.131.0/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/1.128.0/node_modules/vsts-task-lib/toolrunner.js:569:30)
        at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: more than one library with package name com.google.android.gms.license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398026/error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-license)

Comment: no its about cordova  and my question is about react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried some of the solutions posted here without success, and I really did not want to delve into `node_modules`, but that is what I have done since my project is time sensitive. At least until a permanent solution is found.

In my app-level `build.gradle`, I have updated all Google dependencies to version 11.8.0, e.g. `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0"`. Then in `react-native-onesignal's build.gradle`:

I changed these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
```

to the same specific version as follows:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
```

That seems to fix the error. If anyone has a better solution, I'll gladly implement that in the project. In the meantime, I hope this helps someone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

go to project.properties and change the following lines:

cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+

To

cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11+

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

just add these line in your code block

```
          configurations.all{  

           //here include these line
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
         }
```

Comment: it working for some dependencies but not for all  like onesignal is also using google service so it cause error again

Comment: check your onesignal build.gradle file in node_module  and from there comment out ('com.google.android.gms) dependency

Comment: that solution is not valid as any modification in node_modules are good for local changes only

Comment: tell me what dependency are using in your react-native-onesignal build.gradle file or add  these line                                                     force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.0'   with those 2 lines as I mentioned above .hope this will solve

Comment: glad to hear that.

Comment: @Ray M. Shigoli you don't need to modify node_module.just Add those dependency file in your ./android/build.gradle  file like this    configurations.all{  

           //here include these line
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
            force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
         }

Answer (score 0):

its simple as i am struggling with my project i find out that any dependencies you have used in your project all are using '+' and now its not working anymore so apply specific version to it by doing

in : android/build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
              force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0"
              .... your other dependencies
            }
        }
```

this worked for me as I stuck in onesignal but i got all dependences form onesignal and give it specific version and now everything is working fine