# More than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

Tags: java, android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using angular 4 and ionic 3. Now when i run "ionic cordova run android"
It gives me the following error:

```
 "more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'"
```

My project.property file:

```
target=android-26

   android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib   
   cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0    
   cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0    
   cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0    
   cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+    
   cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-firebase/starter-build.gradle    
   cordova.system.library.5=com.google.gms:google-services:+    
   cordova.system.library.6=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+    
   cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+    
   cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+    
   cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+    
   cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+
```

My dependencies in build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
 // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
 debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
 releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
 compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0"
 compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+"
 compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
 compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"
 compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
 compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
 compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+"
 compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"
 // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
         }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: more than one library with package name com.google.android.gms.license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398026/error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-license)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your project.property file to:

```
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:25.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.9=me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar
```

Answer (score 6):

Please update your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
 }
```

changes your version to `2.3.0`

its worked for me...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue comes here:

> compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
>
> compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"

Rather than importing gms services like this, you should only import specific libraries.

Comment: and how can i do that ? @Akash

Comment: you can  look for gradle import links on  google for specific libraries or if you want you can use "exclude" tag, so that same libraries won't import again

Answer (score 0):

You are using together those both library.

```
compile "com.google.gms:google-services:+"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"
```

this `"com.google.gms:google-services:+"` library has all play service libraries.

Remove this dependency `"com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"` and it will work.

But still This is not a good way to add `com.google.gms:google-services:+`, because un-necessary you are adding all google's dependency.

Instead of this dependecy you can use specific dependency, for example if you are using map, then use only map play service.

Here is the list of all play service dependency https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup .

I suggest you add only required dependency instead of play service universal dependency.

Comment: M not using MAP.. i'm just using firebase @vishal

Comment: That was for example. instead of using + version, use specific version for firebase. you can get from firebase [site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Answer (score 0):

- If you've already changed version at /android/build.gradle but not work yet. Maybe you need check some library package at node_modules.
- Eg: react-native-onesignal also compile some play-services with highest version (they use +) so it can make this issue.
- You can put a script at root directory and add {"scripts": {"postinstall": "node changeVersionGoogleService.js"}} in package .json so it can run to auto change your version when you npm install.
- This is the script: https://gist.github.com/duytq94/47ef945131b61de538447d449813b3d4
- My script at now auto change 'react-native-onesignal',
  'react-native-admob',
  'react-native-maps',
  'react-native-google-sign-in'

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions discussed here worked for me so I went on to

- renamed the `/platform/android` folder and Remove android platform
- add android platform `ionic cordova platform add android`
- faced another issue with facebook due to this which has a solution [here](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/599) where you need to add your app id and name in `platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` file

compiled worked fine after that.

The problem occurred for me when **upgrading to cordova 7**.

Answer (score 0):

just Add :

```
googlePlayServicesVersion=11.8.0
```

to your gradle.properties

have fun ...